# Percentage width referred to the parent of the parent

Tags: html, css, parent-child, percentage

I am trying to figure out if there is some way to make a percentage refer to the parent of the parent.

In the below example case, I would like the text to have the width of the green div, not the width of its direct parent which is the white one.

```css
#fluid {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background: olive;
  position: absolute;
}

#fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#text {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fluid">
  <article id="fixed">
    <h3 id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
  </article>
</div>
```

Is there some way I could achieve this using only CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to make an element have width relevant **directly** to its grandparent. You can, however, make the parent 100% of the grandparent, and have the target element a percentage width of its own parent:

```
#fluid {
  width: 75vw;
}

#fixed {
  width: 100%;
}

#text {
  width: 50% /* 37.5vw */
}
```

Having a 'middle' div with a fixed width and a child that's relevant to its grandparent is unfortunately impossible, as the child can only be relative to its direct parent.

One solution to what you're trying to achieve (in a typical scenario) would be to move `#text` out of `#fixed`, and have them both positioned absolutely, with `#fluid` positioned relatively. They would both occupy the same area, giving the same desired effect :)

```
<div id="fluid">
  <article id="fixed"></article>
  <h3 id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
</div>

#fluid {
  position: relative;
  width: 75vw;
}

#fixed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50% /* 37.5vw */
}
```

Though it sounds as though you would ultimately have  multiple `.article`s and only one `#fluid`, so that HTML structure may not suit.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) That is what I thought, but maybe using rem units or similar? I'm not much keen in those.

Comment: `rem` and `em` units are both relative to `font-size`. You *could* use them, but you would still face the issue of the fixed container in the middle (as both `rem` and `em` always relative) :)